# Token id and the scripting of it

Tags: performance, security, testing, loadrunner

I have a security token id with number "87654321", there are around 8 boxes the 1st box takes the number 6, the 4th box takes the number 2, the 6th box takes the number 4 and the 8th box takes the number 3. there are remaining of 4 boxes the remaining number needs to be filled. the token id is always the same but the number when it goes to the box is random and only 4 numbers are been put into the box. how to place the remaining number? Is there any function used?

Comment: Kindly help me out on this

Comment: You need to parametrize the input of the rest of the boxes and write some code to calculate the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Tokens are there to defeat automation in many respects and to validate identity.  Also, many are third party services.  If this is a third party service is it one that you have an SLA with and one which you are coordinating with as part of your test activities.  If not, then cut that piece out of your test.

If this is a third party service and you are coordinating then this token piece is a common performance testing challenge.  They should have a way to make the pattern consistent for you during testing.

If this is in-house code then just make the pattern fixed for your testing window.

Comment: Is there any function that is been used in load runner to substitute the numbers in to the boxes?

Comment: Boxes are a GUI construct.  An HTTP virtual user would operate below the GUI

Comment: So there is no functions that is been used in load runner to perform the above task, this was a question to me by HCL employee in an interview. I too answered the same but he kept on insisting that there is an function. thanks James.

Comment: It was probably a question downloaded from an interview questions site and the interviewer was looking for the answer from the site.  The only problem with that model is that those sites are peppered with questions which have deliberately incorrect answers as control questions to be asked in interviews to see who __really__ knows the answer and who was downloading questions and answers from interview sites